# How do you escape html in answers?

Tags: support, design, escape-character

I expect to be downvoted to hell but I'm having trouble finding the answer to this

I'm trying to write: `<a href="url">`

but clearly you can't see that because i can't escape it

I see now that it's backticks thanks anthony

Comment: Oops, I answered your question by way of editing it.

Comment: YES YOU DID how did you do that

Comment: I'm up voting the answer and the question at the same time!

Comment: @JoeFrambach But I don't receive any rep for that :(

Comment: i'll accept your answer if you post it

Comment: This question is already closed and will not accept any answers.